# Multiple loops with PHP foreach?

Tags: php

$result contains an array of data items from a database query.

$A is an empty array. I also have created an empty array called $B and so on.

I want to loop through all 26 letters of the alphabet. For each letter I want to loop through the array containing my database query results and push them onto their respective array. So 'Ant' and 'Antelope' get pushed onto array $A, 'Buffalo' onto array $B and so on.

Here's my problem PHP:

```
$letter = 'A';
  for($count = 1; $count <= 26; ++$count) {
    foreach ($result as $topic) {
      if (substr($topic->animal, 0, 1) == $letter //the first letter is A, B...
        array_push($A, $topic->animal);
      }
    }
  }
  $letter++;
}
```

1. I think the internal array pointer is being moved to the end of $result because I only get animals starting with the letter A being pushed onto array $A. All other arrays ($B, $C etc.) are empty. In any case it only works once (for the letter A). reset($result) doesn't seem to work. How can I loop through $result multiple (26) times?
2. How do I change the array to be pushed onto when looping through the letters? In other words when $letter is incremented to B I want: array_push($B, $topic->animal);

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't increment `$letter` like that

Comment: @BrendanBullen Yes you can.

Comment: @Kolink Ah yes! Indeed you can. Well, you learn something new every day.

Comment: Had to google this - very suprised that it's possible. Found this: http://joshualuckers.nl/2010/03/02/php-increment-alphabet-characters/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are always pushing onto `A`, so it makes sense that it won't affect any other array.
2. You can use `array_push($$letter,$topic->animal);` (Variable variables) but it's not recommended - you should use a nested array insted with `array_push($letters[$letter],$topic->animal)`

That said, try this:

```
$letters = Array();
foreach($result as $topic) {
    $letters[substr($topic->animal,0,1)][] = $topic->animal;
}
```

Comment: Good comment! But you should type array() lowercased.

Comment: @BramGerritsen If it were my own code, it would be `$letters = [];` instead, but it's not so nyah. Or something XD